# sublime text not opening from command line tmux

Tags: macos, tmux

I have Sublime Text as an alias so I can call it from the terminal on MacOS.

Since I started using tmux, Running the following command opens sublime but not on the current directory.  It's like aliases are not accepting arguments on tmux.

```
subl .
```

Without tmux this command works fine.

Any known issue with tmux alias arguments?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this problem? I am running into the same issue?

Comment: @Alexander - not really, I just stopped using that command which is a shame :/

Comment: same here, I just stopped using the command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/522055/subl-w-doesnt-ever-un-block-when-running-under-tmux-on-os-x) did the trick for me.

```
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

And then append the following to your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```

Lastly, source the config file for tmux

```
tmux source ~/.tmux.conf
```

I use `subl .` all the time! It's a shame you've trained yourself not to use this helpful command.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue after reinstalling Homebrew. Not sure why it happened but i was able to resolve it but just add the following line to the end of my `.bash_profile`.

```
alias subl='open -a "/Applications/Sublime Text.app"'
```

Then closing and reopening the terminal session or by running `source ~/.bash_profile` to reload the profile.

Comment: this works but would prevent you from using any of the regular arguments you can pass to the subl binary.